# Increasing memory limit for electron renderer process?

Tags: electron

**Short**

I am building an electron app with Vue, using [electron-vue](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue). I need it to run a heavy work, say `f()`. But out of memory error is thrown and it cannot be done. How can I increase memory limit of electron renderer process?

---

**Long**

First, when I build a CLI app and run `f()`, i.e.:

```js
// Start of file

function f() {
  // Do some heavy work
}

if (require.main === module) {
  f()
}

// End of file
```

It takes a long time, but `f()` is completed  without any error.

---

However, when I build an electron app and run `f()` in a renderer, it takes a long time and finally throws out of memory error.

My app has the following structure:

```
+----------+                 +------+                 +----------+
| UI       |--work request-->| Main |--work request-->| Worker   |
| renderer |<-work response--| proc |<-work response--| renderer |
+----------+                 +------+                 +----------+
```

The main process forwards request and response. (You may think *Worker renderer* is a bit weird, but I need to keep this structure for a while...)

---

My guess is that difference of memory limit between CLI app and the worker renderer of the electron app causes this problem.

Is my guess is correct? If so, is there any suggestion to solve this problem?

Comment: without seeing actual impl of f(), there's no way to tell your guess is correct or not.

Comment: `f()` is quite big so it's hard to simplify, currently. But the point is that `f()` reads text file with `fs.readFileSync()` and converts text into json object. It does not write a file. It does not use network communication, etc. How much it should be detailed to get a clue?

Comment: `point is that f() reads text file with fs.readFileSync() and converts text into json object.` is very common thing also and I do a lot in my code as well. Especially for memory issue, it's all about details what's done in code. Yes, in theory reading a large file can obviously cause memory but that doesn't mean your code is hitting it. If you assume that's culprit in your code, I believe you should try isolate and share reproducible code to analyze it.